# Fredhopper Live attribute values alias

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

I want to enable templateid as live attribute in fh. What i want to achieve is this: 
When user tries to create filter by using templateid when creating new SmartTarget rule, he needs to know id of template, which is not user friendly. I was thinking if it is possible to map those templateid values to Template name somehow in configuration.

Is it possible and how?

Also, i see that there is templatetitle attribute. Can I maybe use that?

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to provide labels for trigger values that are different from the actual values (e.g. title instead of ID). But it requires you to use the API to set it up and it's kind of complicated.

In this case, you already have the Title available as the 'templatetitle' attribute so you can indeed just use that instead.

Comment: Yes, that seems like most logical way to go. But, if i use templatetitle, its of type text, where templateid is of type list. This will in addition mean that user needs to type template title, which is still better than templateid but not "optimal". I was hopping to get into nitty gritty stuff. :)

Comment: Well, you can define the list of values in trigger-types.xml. If you want to automate it (i.e. synchronize values on changes / new templates), you're going to need to do a lot more work. There is a helper class in the Java API that you could use (it's not part of the official, public API, though) -- I've outlined an approach in an older answer: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12404/how-can-i-manage-list-type-trigger-filter-values-in-smarttarget/12409#12409
Since there is a disconnect between CM and CD, though, this is tricky to do. I'd avoid it if not 100% needed.